# why $http method throwing 500 error but $.ajax is not

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Here is my ajax method working fine

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/users/createUserNew",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    data: $("#createUserForm").serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

but its equivalent $http method is throwing error `500 Internatl Server Error`

here is the code

```
$http.post('/users/createUserNew', $("#createUserForm").serialize())
   .success(function(data){

   });
```

Comment: What is the payload produced by `$("#createUserForm").serialize()`?  I'd check the raw request and look at the body of each.

Comment: You should show the server error for `500 error`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging server side to see why it fails?

Comment: Some servers throw internal server error on PHP error.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The question is why $http is not working but $.ajax is... what I need to fix in $http?

Comment: Can you open your browser's debugging tools and look at the generated network requests? Then compare them, you should find a difference.

Comment: May be something wrong with rewrite rules... `/users/createUserNew` is probably understood as `users/createUserNew` in Angular... but it is a blind guess... you need to check real http requests being sent.

Comment: $http is posting via Payload: emailAddress=user11%40gmail.com&fullName=User11&userGroups=0&phone=123-456-7890&notes=notes

Comment: $ajax is posting via Form Data... I checked via debugger tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add header and try like below

```
$scope.createUser = function() {
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: '/createUserNew',
data: $("#createUserForm").serialize(),
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```